# Heavy tailed multi-variate distribution?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, heavy-tailed

I have been asked to look at some spatial data, which I have assumed is multi-normally distributed in 3 dimensions (and to a reasonable approximation this appears to be true). Actually, all I've been asked to do is provide a table so that someone can specify a probability and I tell them how many standard deviations of their data they need to have that coverage so I wasn't expecting this to take long (i.e. 1.96sd = 95% in 1D).

On a closer inspection of the data it is rather heavy-tailed and based on what I think it's wanted for these are the interesting data so I think I possibly shouldn't be using the normal distribtuion, making this a more interesting task. The only two-tailed, tail heavy distribution I know of is the t-distribution and a quick google search seems to imply that there is not a natural multi-variate extension of this although I could just use the one on wiki. Is there a multi-variate t-distribution that's considered 'best' or is there a better distribution that I should be considering?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a formal distribution? If you have enough data, I think you could use your data itself, and some sort of method like kernel density estimation to get 95% of your data in a 3 dimensional shape.

Comment: I could use the data itself I'm not sure I have enough data for a useful three dimensional estimation although I could certainly do three one dimensional analyses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments:

- There is no "best" multivariate extension of the $t$ distribution. The best choice depends on your needs.
- The most common in practice is the one provided in wikipedia. Take a look at this link ftp://ftp.ecn.purdue.edu/bethel/kotz_mvt.pdf for a discussion on this and other multivariate t distributions. Another important reference is http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Multivariate_T_Distributions_and_Their_A.html?id=dmxtU-TxTi4C&redir_esc=y.
- The R package mvtnorm implements some multivariate $t$ distributions.
- You can create your own version by using a copula, such as the Gaussian copula.